# How to draw and Horizontal list of circle avatars that are on top of each other

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `row` that contains a list of `circle avatars widgets`, which are profile images of people.

[image]

```js
Row(children: [
  for (var i in listOfEvents[i].attendeesList)
      CircleAvatar(
         backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://github.com/identicons/guest.png"),
         radius: 18,
      ),
  ],
 )
```

Am looking for a way to move all the circle avatars a little bit to the left so the avatars seem like they are on top of each other to save space

like this illustration

[image]

I have been trying to add a negative padding or negative position using the `Padding widget` but it doesn't work

If anyone knows how to do the trick it would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a **Stack** which wraps your avatar widgets in **Positioned** widgets, and you can use perhaps the **radius** to adjust the overlapping, as in:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: Stack(
        children: List.generate(
          listOfEvents[i].attendeesList.length, (index) {
            return Positioned(
              left: index * 30,
              child: const CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/61495501?v=4"),
                radius: 30,
              )
            );
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

And you'll end up with something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the Stack widget. It's quite impressive.
Try this. You can add shadows to make it look even better. Remember to replace my fake list with yours :)

```
       SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            for (var i = 0; i < [1, 2, 3, 4].length; i++)
              Positioned(
                left: (i * (1 - .4) * 40).toDouble(),
                top: 0,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  child: Container(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width:2),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Image.network(
                      "https://github.com/identicons/guest.png",
                    ),
                  ),
                  radius: 18,
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: haha you beat me to the answer! good stuff

Comment: I like and tried your solution but then I found a problem apparently with the sized box, it is mandatory to specify its dimensions width, and height otherwise an error occurs when drawing it