# How can i mack like this wedget in flutter exactly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on the application and I need to build this widget which you can then click on the plus icon join to the team the problem is I can't do it like picture exactly  [image: Click]

Comment: Which one? the overlapping widgets or just the plus icon with the dashed border? Start with this answer for the overlapping avatars https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71577607/how-to-draw-and-horizontal-list-of-circle-avatars-that-are-on-top-of-each-other/71578010#71578010.

Comment: I need both together

Answer (score 1):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
  child: Stack(
    children: List.generate(
      listOfEvents[i].attendeesList.length, (index) {
        return Positioned(
          left: index * 30,
          child: const CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/61495501?v=4"),
            radius: 30,
          )
        );
      }
    )
  )
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the package called "dotted_border" and follow the given code

`DottedBorder( child: // put your image here //borderType: BorderType.Circle,dashPattern: [10,5,10,5,10,5]),`